# How do linux distros like Debian, Red Hat make many binary packages from one source package?

Tags: package-management, binary, source-code

I wonder how linux distros like Debian, Red Hat, Gentoo, Ubuntu make many binary packages from one package? When I compile package, they just become install all in one. So my questions are:

#### How do they separate them?

#### How do they figure out their dependencies?

Comment: An example of what you mean would be good.

Comment: @Kusalananda I mean in Debian, `gcc` , `g++` , `libstdc++` package is built from one source package GCC.

Comment: Example library : name, name-dev → Run time only is required, so "name-dev" is not installed. ... Example gcc : You don't need e.g. {gnat gccgo gfortran}, but gcc only : `apt install gcc libc6-dev linux-libc-dev` ... or `apt install g++`

Answer (score 1):

When distribution packages are built, the artifacts aren’t installed directly in their target locations. Instead, they are installed to a temporary location, and the packages are built using the contents there.

For source packages which build multiple binary packages, the last step above is split into multiple target packages. Each target package lists the files it’s supposed to contain. See the various `.install` files in [my `libevdev` package](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/libevdev/-/tree/master/debian) for example; the `libevdev` build installs the following files:

```
debian/tmp/usr/include/libevdev-1.0/libevdev/libevdev.h
debian/tmp/usr/include/libevdev-1.0/libevdev/libevdev-uinput.h
debian/tmp/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdev.la
debian/tmp/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdev.a
debian/tmp/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdev.so.2.3.0
debian/tmp/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libevdev.pc
debian/tmp/usr/bin/libevdev-tweak-device
debian/tmp/usr/bin/mouse-dpi-tool
debian/tmp/usr/bin/touchpad-edge-detector
debian/tmp/usr/share/man/man3/libevdev.3
```

(the equivalent of what you’d get by installing with `sudo make install`), and these are split up into

- `libevdev2`:

  ```
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdev.so.2.3.0
  ```
- `libevdev-dev`:

  ```
  /usr/include/libevdev-1.0/libevdev/libevdev.h
  /usr/include/libevdev-1.0/libevdev/libevdev-uinput.h
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libevdev.a
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libevdev.pc
  /usr/share/man/man3/libevdev.3
  ```
- `libevdev-tools`:

  ```
  /usr/bin/libevdev-tweak-device
  /usr/bin/mouse-dpi-tool
  /usr/bin/touchpad-edge-detector
  ```

(The `udeb` is a special case, probably not worth discussing here.)